# Add a menu item to Wordpress 3.5 Media Manager

Tags: media, media-library

How can add a new menu item underneath the "insert From URL" on the left sidebar in the new Wordpress 3.5 Media Manager?

I've been looking at the backbone js and tried my hand at hooking into it with my own JS but without success.

Edit 2:
This seems to do the trick:

http://sumtips.com/2012/12/add-remove-tab-wordpress-3-5-media-upload-page.html

It should do for simple stuff, but I guess its also possible to do the same thing in Javascript. Would be nice if there was a tutorial/explanation on how the new media manager internals work.

Comment: what is your new menu supposed to do? Adding a menu item isn't the main problem and you are on the right track, but if your menu is supposed do display anything different from the default views, just with changed setting, Backbone needs a view for your menu item...and thats where I'm stucked as well...

Comment: clicking on the menu item is supposed to show a different view. Getting the menu item to show up would be a first step

Comment: Regarding my 150 point bouny: Looking to continue the original poster's aim to use a JS-based method to add a new State menu item below "Insert from URL" and associate a new view in the primary media modal of the Post Editor.

Comment: @erezie, can you mark the answer on this as the one provided by Fabien Quatravaux?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK, I think that I have something that is really close to be an answer:

I put my code in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/4586865)

Here is the result :
[image: custom menu screenshot]

I built several Backbone object to respect the MVC pattern : the `controller.Custom` is in charge of doing all the logic, the `view.Toolbar.Custom` deals with toolbar buttons, and the `view.Custom` display the inner UI.

Comment: What is it missing so far?

Comment: +1 good start! But, yes, instead of we needing to implement this to know what it does, a snapshot would be *very handy*. And also, pull that line of comment `//build an empty view (needs more work)` to the content of the Answer.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to show the result. The next thing to do now is to implement the view itself that will display HTML components and react to user interaction.

Comment: This looks cool, that's definitely a start! Worthy of the bounty as is, but feel free to take it to the next level if you feel the need.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty Scott ! I will definitely dig a bit deeper because I need it for a project at work. I will post my code back here as soon as it will be usable.

Comment: @Scott: I have completed the code to make is fully working. See [the gist](https://gist.github.com/4586865).

Comment: +1, just wanted to say thanks for some very impressive work. You saved me a lot of time today.

Comment: I know this is an older thread, but for anyone who finds it...check out this plugin by Automattic (the folks behind WordPress.com) to see an example of how to extend the WP Media Manager: https://github.com/Automattic/media-explorer/blob/master/js/mexp.js

Comment: Using your plugin I get the following error: 
`TypeError: this.make is not a function
this.input = this.make( 'input', {`. Any ideas?

Comment: @FabienQuatravaux can you put the answer in your answer? You currently link offsite, so your answer does not contain the answer, link answers are frowned upon and your answer becomes useless if the URL ever changes or breaks

Answer (score 10):

I'm working on adding a button to the "router menu" (adding something right of "Media Library"), but the system is the same.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
        var media   = window.wp.media,  
        Attachment  = media.model.Attachment,
        Attachments = media.model.Attachments,
        Query       = media.model.Query,
        l10n = media.view.l10n = typeof _wpMediaViewsL10n === 'undefined' ? {} : _wpMediaViewsL10n,
        NewMenuItem;

        jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.insert-media', function( event ) {
            var workflow = wp.media.editor.get();
            var options = workflow.options;
            if( undefined == NewMenuItem ) {
                NewMenuItem = new wp.media.view.RouterItem( _.extend( options, { text: 'New Item!' } ) );
                workflow.menu.view.views.set( '.media-menu', NewMenuItem, _.extend( options, { add: true } ) );
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, it doesn't do anything yet. That's the next step!

Comment: Any luck on this? A JS-based solution is what I'd really like to see, not the iframe PHP solution already noted in the original poster's edit and another answer

Answer (score 7):

You can hook into the `media_upload_tabs` filter to add the tab. This is the method used by the [Network Shared Media](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/network-shared-media/) plugin:

```
function wpse_76980_add_upload_tab( $tabs ) {
    $newtab = array( 'tab_slug' => 'Tab Name' );
    return array_merge( $tabs, $newtab );
}
add_filter( 'media_upload_tabs', 'wpse_76980_add_upload_tab' );
```

You can then hook to the `media_upload_tab_slug` action (where `tab_slug` is as used above) to display the tab contents:

```
function wpse_76980_media_upload() {
    // display tab contents
}
add_action( 'media_upload_tab_slug', 'wpse_76980_media_upload' );
```

Comment: This is the old way of adding a tab. Although it is still working but I suspect that WP is moving away from it.

Comment: @Jenny, I think we [may count](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/media.php#L1439) on this filter. Relevant [ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22186#comment:46). (:oh, and +1, nice snipett:)

Answer (score 3):

I have not a solution, but hints. The strings get from a array. You can filter via hook `media_view_strings`. The modal box after click is a javascript, build with backbone.js since WP 3.5. See in `/wp-includes/js/media-views.js` for a solution. Backbone is also new for me and the scripts have many lines of source.

Comment: That was a very nice hint, but I think it falls short. The `media.view.settings` js var can be tweaked  by a php filter to add new tabs, but then those tabs are rendered via an iframe (see `createIframeStates` method in `media-views.js`).

Comment: Maybe you can add a tutorial, gist to your blog o.o. to add a simple link inside the media view and a custom action on click on this link? Your current gist is very complex and have lot of custom actions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find another simpler way to achieve this. [This code](https://gist.github.com/Fab1en/4586865) is doing only one basic thing : add a custom menu item on the left, with its own content view, toolbar and controller. All this construction is needed to built the views and controller needed by Backbone. But if you have a simpler solution, feel free to fork my gist.

Comment: Yes, I have see this and also test it, works fine. But I think it was nice, that you create also a gist only for a button or link and a callback funktion inside the default media screen, not a additional part, how in your example.