# How to extend Media Library (WP 4.4)

Tags: plugins, media, media-library, media-modal

I am trying to implement a new tab next to Media Library. I couldn't find solution to implement this. I found an example how to implement a new tab in this link: https://gist.github.com/Fab1en/4586865 However the tab doesn't show up in the modal form triggered by Add Media button. But if I call the media popup for Featured Image or any other custom button the "New Tab" I created shows up. I am really lost here, not sure why those tabs show up in one place and don't in another.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Um, take a look at http://www.pendingdraft.net/2015/01/intro-to-wp-media/ and https://github.com/ericandrewlewis/wp-media-javascript-guide. There might be something in there. I've been wondering the same thing for quite a while.

Comment: Maybe a filter in the dropdown is better than a new tab, what do you want to show in the new tab?

Comment: @cybmeta I would like to add new file upload form different from the one in the first tab.

Comment: That sound confusing. Do you want two "Upload" tabs? Have you thought in customize the standard "Upload" tab instead of creating a new one? See [this question and answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76980/add-a-menu-item-to-wordpress-3-5-media-manager/), specially [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77275/37428).

Comment: @cybmeta I saw both links and I know how to add new tabs to the left sidebar. Instead I need to add a new tab horizontally just like in the image. I feel like it has something to do with Media View controller, but can't find any documentation on how to extend it. If I add a new tab to the left sidebar the new option won't be available in some cases (like when you choose Featured image etc..).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Most of the times, the items in the left sidebar of the modal wndow are just called "menu", not "tabs". Anyway, you have not said nothing about why cusomizing the existent upload tab is not good for you and why you need to create a new one totally from scratch.

Comment: @cybmeta, I recently created something similar with a DropBox uploader. The menus on the right only show when adding to a post. When you're in the regular Media section you only see the top tabs. It made more sense to create an extra uploader UI then try to modify the main screen.

Comment: @jgraup That's exactly what I am trying to do. To be honest this is going to be one of the first wordpress plugins that I am creating.

Comment: Take a look at that plugin above. It actually includes code to control the views in Backbone and other examples which may help. But I really want to know this same thing. Are you using Dropbox as the uploader?

Comment: @jgraup Yes, I need to use Dropbox as the uploader. Thanks for those links! I will do some research and create a prototype!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5KPXLzuBXE some more research...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a tab but you might be able to get started with an upload button. Check out [`pre-upload-ui`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L1826) and some actions that follow. Namely [`pre-plupload-upload-ui`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L1902) and [`post-upload-ui`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L1956).

This will add a couple buttons to the '**Upload Files**' tab and to '**Media > Add New**'.

**BUTTONS**

```
add_action( 'pre-plupload-upload-ui', 'wpse_20160202_pre_plupload_upload_ui' );
add_action( 'post-upload-ui', 'wpse_20160202_post_upload_ui' );

function wpse_20160202_pre_plupload_upload_ui()
{
    # see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L1902

    print '<button onclick="javascript:alert(\'Upload From Dropbox\');" id="db-upload-btn" class="button media-button button-primary button-large" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Upload From Dropbox</button>';
}


function wpse_20160202_post_upload_ui()
{
    # see wp-includes/media-template.php

    print '<button onclick="javascript:alert(\'Another Upload From Dropbox\');" id="db-upload-btn" class="button media-button button-primary button-large" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Another Upload From Dropbox</button>';
}
```

**TABS**

Adding this here just to show the alternate. [`media_upload_tabs`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_upload_tabs/) will help you control which tabs are included in the side and [`media_upload_{tab}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_upload_tab/) to render the contents using [`wp_iframe()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_iframe).

```
add_filter( 'media_upload_tabs', 'media_upload_tabs__tab_slug' );

function media_upload_tabs__tab_slug( $tabs ) {
    $newtab = array ( 'tab_slug' => 'Your Tab Name' );
    return array_merge( $tabs, $newtab );
}

add_action( 'media_upload_tab_slug', 'media_upload_tab_slug__content' );

function media_upload_tab_slug__content() {
    wp_iframe( 'media_upload_tab_slug_content__iframe' );
}

function media_upload_tab_slug_content__iframe() {
    ?>
    <div>tab_slug: Add your content here.</div><?php
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! In fact this is what I was looking for initially! Thank you for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this problem after many days of research.

For a better understanding, you can check my short video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEr-WmVMkAQ

```js
var frame = wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Post;
wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Post = frame.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    frame.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

    var State = wp.media.controller.State.extend({
      insert: function () {
        console.log("Something...");
        this.frame.close();
      }
    });

    this.states.add([
      new State({
        id: "ademedia",
        search: false,
        title: "Ade Media"
      })
    ]);

    //on render
    this.on("content:render:ademedia", this.renderAdemediaContent, this);
  },
  browseRouter: function (routerView) {
    routerView.set({
      upload: {
        text: wp.media.view.l10n.uploadFilesTitle,
        priority: 20
      },
      ademedia: {
        text: "Ade Media",
        priority: 30
      },
      browse: {
        text: wp.media.view.l10n.mediaLibraryTitle,
        priority: 40
      }
    });
  },
  renderAdemediaContent: function () {
    var AdemediaContent = wp.Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: "div",
      className: "ademediacontent",
      template: wp.template("ademedia"),
      active: !1,
      toolbar: null,
      frame: null
    });

    var view = new AdemediaContent();

    this.content.set(view);
  }
});
```